Find all pairs of positive compatible numbers less than $100$
A pair of positive integers is called compatible if one of the numbers equals the sum of all digits in the pair and the other number equals the product of all digits in the pair. Find all pairs of positive compatible numbers less than $100$.
I let $x$ and $y$ be compatible numbers, where $x$ is the sum and $y$ is the product of their digits. Note that all digits are non-zero as $y$ must not be $0$. I consider three cases; When $x$ has a single digit, when $x$ has two digits and $y$ has a single digit, and when $x$ and $y$ have two digits each.
Case $1$: When $x$ has a single digit.
Since $y$ has a positive digit, we reach $x\ge x+1$, a contradiction. Hence, $x$ must have two digits.
Case 2: When x has two digits and y has a single digit.
We'll have $x=10a+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive digits. Then $10a+b=a+b+y$ and $y=aby$. From the second equation we can determine that $a$ and $b$ must equal $1$.
Substituting into the first equation, $y=9$. The only pair of compatible numbers when $x$ has two digits and $y$ has a single digit must be $x=11$ and $y=9$.
Case 3: When both $x$ and $y$ have two digits.
This is the part that I am unsure about; not sure how to prove this case. I just need a method of reaching the answer so you do not need to follow my method.
Furthermore, an extension question asks:

Find all pairs of positive compatible numbers less than $1000$ with at least one number greater than $99$.

Thanks!

Here’s a method that should help you:
Set $x = 10a + b$ and $y = 10c + d$ where $1 \le a,b,c,d\le 9$ (since none of the digits can be $0$ as you pointed out). We have:
$$10a + b = a + b + c + d$$
$$10c + d = abcd$$
The first equation simplifies to
$$9a = c + d,$$
which simplifies the second equation to
$$9a + 9c = abcd.$$
Therefore, both $c+d$ and $abcd$ must be divisible by $9$. We see that either $c$ and $d$ both have factors of $3$, or neither do, in which case both $a$ and $b$ have a factor of $3$ or one of them has a factor of $9$. This should simplify the problem enough to work casewise (for example, trying $c = 3$ and $d = 6$ yields the solution $x = 12, y = 36$).
Let me know if you need more help!

The first thing that I did was to put this into WolframAlpha; specifically, I used the query (link):

solve over Z+: (a+b+c+d) = 10a + b && a*b*c*d = 10c + d

This is to see whether we have a pair of the form $("ab", "cd")$ where the quotation marks are to indicate that the actual numbers meant are $(10a+b, 10c+d)$. Once you convince yourself that this is impossible when any of the digits is zero, you can do the search over the positive integers, $\mathbb{Z}^+$. A further restriction would include that each of the digits is between one and nine; as it turns out, Wolfram finds only one solution:
$$(12, 36)$$
We can verify that this is a solution by checking: $1+2+3+6 = 12$, which is the first element; moreover, we have that $1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot6 = 36$, which is the second element. Success!
Now, it seems that you want a proof of this by hand (?). How about:
The first condition forces $c+d = 9a$, and the second condition says that
$$abcd = 9c + (c+d) = 9c + 9a = 9(c+a)$$
Now, remembering that each of $a,b,c,d$ is a digit in $\{1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$, there are not so many ways in which we can have two of them, $c$ and $d$, sum to $9a$. In particular, this can only happen if $c+d = 9(1)$ or perhaps if $c+d = 9(2)$, where the latter is realized only if $c=d=9$. Investigate this latter case and you will see it cannot be achieved.
Let's investigate the former case, i.e., when $c+d = 9$, and we have $a = 1$.
So the numbers, as they currently stand, are:
$$("ab", "cd") = ("1b", "c[9-c]")$$
If you run through the nine possible values of $b$, you will find only one solution: Specifically, the one that was found above using WolframAlpha.

a similar search finds, for your latter question, solutions at $(135, 19)$ and $(144, 19)$. given that these solutions work, you might try supposing both numbers are $\geq 20$ ... and aim for a contradiction. not sure how much trickery (especially around divisibility by 9) can be employed versus brute force searching for this question!

For the $3$-digit question it is not hard to show that the sum of all digits is at most $29$.

As the initial question in blockquotes does not specify a base, I'll answer for a general integer base $b\geq2$.
Let $x$ and $y$ be two positive base $b$-compatible numbers less than $100=b^2$. Then we can write
$$x=x_1b+x_0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=y_1b+y_0,$$
for integers $0\leq x_0,x_1,y_0,y_1<b$. Interchanging $x$ and $y$ if necessary, the pair $(x,y)$ is compatible if
$$x=x_0+x_1+y_0+y_1\qquad\text{ and }\qquad y=x_0x_1y_0y_1.$$
Given that $x$ and $y$ are positive, we immediately see that $x_0x_1y_0y_1>0$. It follows that $x,y\geq b+1$. We also see that
$$x_1b+x_0=x=x_0+x_1+y_0+y_1\qquad\text{ so }\qquad x_1(b-1)=y_0+y_1\leq2(b-1),$$
which shows that $x_1\leq2$, so either $x_1=1$ or $x_1=2$. Moreover, if $x_1=2$ it follows that $y_0=y_1=b-1$ and so we get
\begin{eqnarray}
y&=&y_1b+y_0=(b-1)b+(b-1)=(b+1)(b-1)\\
y&=&x_0x_1y_0y_1=2x_0(b-1)(b-1),
\end{eqnarray}
from which it follows that $b+1=2x_0(b-1)$, so $x_0=1$ and $b=3$, giving the solution
$$(x,y)=((21)_3,(22)_3).$$
Any other solution must then have $x_1=1$ and $y_0+y_1=b-1$. We get
\begin{eqnarray*}
y&=&y_1b+y_0=y_1b+(b-1-y_1)=(y_1+1)(b-1),\\
y&=&x_0x_1y_0y_1=x_0(b-1-y_1)y_1=-x_0y_1^2+x_0(b-1)y_1,
\end{eqnarray*}
which shows that $y_1$ divides $b-1$, as we already saw that $y_1\neq0$, say $b-1=z_0y_1$. Then
$$(y_1+1)z_0y_1=-x_0y_1^2+x_0z_0y_1^2,$$
which shows that $y_1$ divides $z$, or equivalently, that $y_1^2$ divides $b-1$, and so we can write $b-1=z_1y_1^2$. Plugging this in and dividing by $y_1^2$ yields
$$(y_1+1)z_1=-x_0+x_0z_1y_1=x_0(z_1y_1-1),$$
which shows in particular that $z_1y_1-1>0$, because the left hand side is positive, and so
$$x_0=\frac{z_1y_1+z_1}{z_1y_1-1}=1+\frac{z_1+1}{z_1y_1-1}.$$
Of course $x_0$ is a positive integer the fraction on the right hand side must also be an integer. This implies $y_1\leq3$ and a routine check then shows that $(y_1,z_1)$ is one of
$$(1,2),\qquad(1,3),\qquad(2,1),\qquad(2,2),\qquad(3,1).$$
The first pair corresponds to $(x,y,b)=((14)_3,(11)_3,3)$, which is of course not a solution because $(14)_3$ is not a valid representation. The next pairs correspond to the following solutions $(x,y,b)$, in order:
$$((13)_4,(12)_4,4),
\qquad((13)_5,(22)_5,5),
\qquad((12)_9,(26)_9,9),
\qquad((12)_{10},(36)_{10},10).$$
Together with the solution $((21)_3,(22)_3,3)$ we found earlier, these are all solutions.
